# is it possible to rename event label in google analytics?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics

How to rename event action and event label field in google analytics?
I want to change some meaningful name for that field.
I don't want to create custom variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you sent the event action "button" with an Event Label of "home", and now you want to change "button" to "link" and "home" to "Cat".

You can't; once data is inserted into Google Analytics it can't be updated.  Start sending with the new values; now the old ones are there to stay.

**Update**

If you want to change the column name in the Google Analytics website "Event Action" to something like "my Button Clicks" then you can't do that either - that's a standard Google Analytics column you don't have access to change that.

Comment: No, not like that.

Comment: i want to rename column field "event action".

Comment: You cant do that either that's a Standard field in Google Analytics